# Where to free memory, while creating 2d array? valgrind error

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am starting to learn dynamic memory allocation. In this code, I have created in **main** function 2d array:

```
int r, c;
scanf("%d %d\n", &r, &c);
size_t row = (size_t) r;
size_t col = (size_t) c;
int **board = malloc(row * sizeof(*board));                                                                       
for (int i = 0; i < r; i++) {                                                                                                     
   board[i] = malloc(col * sizeof(*board[i]));
}
```

(I need both int and size_t because of for loops, especially when r>=0, which is always true for size_t).

Then I change the board with other functions. Valgrind returs:

```
==59075== 364 (56 direct, 308 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 2 of 2                    
==59075==    at 0x483577F: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:299)                                                             
==59075==    by 0x10B4DB: main (name22.c:122)                                                                        
==59075==
```

122 line is:

```
int **board = malloc(row*sizeof( *board));
```

I suppose I have to use free(), but after checking other answers I don't know, where is my mistake and where to put free(), if use use this table through the rest of the program. I would appreciate your hints and explanations.
`

Comment: If you did anything to change the address of `board`, then the memory that was created is now orphaned.  Provide enough of the code to illustrate the problem, at least a [mcve]

Comment: If you are using the memory blocks until the end of your program, then you should call `free` as the last thing you do in the function `main`. Under no circumstances should you access the memory block after calling `free`, otherwise your program will be causing [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Also, remember not to call `free` only once, but once for every call to `malloc`. So you must also call it in a loop, as you did with `malloc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `int **board = malloc(row * sizeof(*board));` , the system will allocate you `row * sizeof(*board)` bytes of memory and then return a pointer to the start of that memory (ie - a memory address), which you are storing in the `int **` variable called `board`.

When your program finishes, the system will reclaim that memory, so if your program is short lived, it probably doesn't matter very much, but it's good practise to get into the habit of freeing your memory because it will not reclaim **any memory at all** until your program exits, **unless you tell it to**.

For that reason, you should always call `free(...)`, passing in the memory address you were given when you first called `malloc(...)`, once you are done with that memory. In *most* cases, each call to `malloc(...)` should have an equal and opposite call to `free(...)`

This is important because your system has a finite amount of memory. If your program is asking for resources and then never giving them back when they are done you will eventually run out of memory - this is what is called a "memory leak".

So for you, calling `free(...)` correctly, is going to look something like this:

```js
int **board = malloc(row * sizeof(*board));                                                                       
for (int i = 0; i < r; i++) {                                                                                                     
   board[i] = malloc(col * sizeof(*board[i]));
}

// Do something with board

for (int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
   free(board[i]);
}
free(board);
```

Comment: When you call `int **board = malloc(row * sizeof(*board));` , the system will allocate a block of memory sufficient to hold `row` number of pointers.. (I think that is what you are saying). Then it allocates `row` number of blocks to hold `col` number of `int` each and assigns the beginning address to each of the pointers in-turn.. Then to free,  you work in reverse order freeing each of the blocks of `col` number of `int` before calling free on the pointers.